# Using whereHas to make filter query in laravel returns empty data?

Tags: php, laravel

I have roles and admins table and pivot table for admin_role

roles table structure

`id, role_name, slug`

admins table structure

`id, name, email, phone`

admin_role table structure

`id, role_id, admin_id`

Admin.php Model

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'admin_role');
}
```

Role.php Model

```
public function admins() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Admin::class,'admin_role');  
}
```

AdminController.php

```
public function getTeams() {
    try {
        $selectedName = request('name');
        $selectedRole = request('role');
        $selectedPhone = request('phone');
        $admins = Admin::with(['roles','resources'])
            ->when($selectedName, function($query) use($selectedName) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' .$selectedName.'%');
            })
            ->when($selectedPhone, function($query) use($selectedPhone) {
                $query->where('phone_number', $selectedPhone);
            })
            ->when($selectedRole, function($query) use($selectedRole) {
                $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($selectedRole){
                    $q->whereIn('role_id', $selectedRole);
                });
            })
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);
        return response()->json($admins);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        $e = "Get teams Api Error";
        return response()->json($e);
    }
}
```

The above query was working fine, it was filtering data based on selected Name, Phone but after adding whereHas clause for role-based filtering, it returns empty array. Filtering works only when I passed data in selected Role.

Any suggestions on where I made the mistake.

I have added my UI of admin table.

[image: admin table]

without applying any of the filter like (name, email, phone, role) it should display data based on default query that i have added. Once the filter option are selected it should show data based on that filter parameter.

My problem : If I passed role than the data gets displayed in table but if there is no any filter selected than there is empty table rather than default data.

After I removed below query from `AdminController` data is returned to `UI table` but if I add it, then data gets returned only if role are selected.

```
->when($selectedRole, function($query) use($selectedRole) {
    $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($selectedRole){
        $q->whereIn('role_id', $selectedRole);
    });
})
```

Comment: What you get in $selectedRole ? It is single value or an array?

Comment: it's an array like ["1","2"]

Comment: Try to change:                     $q->whereIn('role_id', $selectedRole); to
                    $q->whereIn('id', $selectedRole);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve you issue by mentioning table name `admin_role` in query like below

```
$q->whereIn('admin_role.role_id', $selectedRole);
```

or

```
$q->whereIn('admin_role.id', $selectedRole);
```

**Updated**

```
->when((isset($selectedRole)&&count($selectedRole)), function($query) use($selectedRole) {
    $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($selectedRole){
      $q->whereIn('admin_role.id', $selectedRole);
    });
})
```

Comment: same issues, it returns empty array

Comment: @anji. i have update answer.it should be admin_role

Comment: `->when($selectedRole, function($query) use($selectedRole) {
                    $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($selectedRole){
                        $q->whereIn('roles.id', $selectedRole);
                    });
                })` this query should only execute if there is any selectedRole value otherwise the query will be executed normally as it is without applying filter. It is because of this query that returns empty array without any filter applied.

Comment: @anji.its not roles.id.check my updated answer

Comment: Not working again, I think the issue is with whereHas

Comment: @if empty role then it wont exicute wherehas

Comment: then why is it working only if i passed selectedRole, without passing role the data should come by default and also other filters are not working if i add this code

Comment: you can test by dd() inside when .so we can verify without selecting role its exicuting ior not

Comment: I have changed some code in controller then it worked as per my requirement.

Comment: @Anji.great to hear you have solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks to you for your suggestion